# Can't calculate cumulative distrubtion

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given $X$ continuous random variable
$f(x) =$
\begin{cases}
\frac{k^3}{2} x^2 e^{-kx},       & {x \geq 0 , k \gt 0} \\
0, & { x \lt 0, k \gt 0}
\end{cases}

For this function i need to calculate the cumultative distribution (i.e. $P(X \leq x$) ).  I got this:

$F(x) =$
\begin{cases}
0,       & {x \lt 0 , k \gt 0} \\
1 - \frac{k^2x^2+2kx+2}{2} e^{-kx}, & { x \geq 0, k \gt 0}
\end{cases}

But i can't obtain $F(x) = 1$, so where am I wrong?

Comment: $F(\infty)=1$, as expected.

Comment: Yes, but i can't do that, can I ? x >= 0, but x can be any number from 0 to infinity.

Comment: And ? What is wrong ?

Comment: This means i'll have a third branch for F(x) = 1 as x-> inf?

Answer (score 1):

You want to show your CDF $\to1$ as $x\to\infty$. This follows from the famous result $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^ne^{-kx}$ for $k>0$.

Incidentally, this is a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with $\alpha=3,\,\beta=k$. In fact, it's an [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution).

Comment: So i'll have a third branch for F(x) = 1 as x -> inf ?

Comment: @AndreiManolache You can write $F(\infty)=1$ if you like, but what you've written is fine as it not only gives $F(x)$ for all real $x$, but also guarantees $P(X\in\Bbb R)=1$ because $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$.